# How to use PDFCreator COM in .net?

Tags: .net, pdf, docx, converters

I read that once you install pdfcreator, you will get the COM interface to use it for your own applications. I am currently using .net and would like to know how the docx file are converted to pdf using a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PDFsharp & Migradoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)

It s opensource and the documentation page is great